# Check if multiple ranges of letters are defined

Tags: regex

I've got a table with this structure and content:

```
A|B|C|D|E
---------
F|G|H|I|J
---------
K|L|M|N|O
```

Now, users can click on multiple letters: If a user

- clicks on A the response string is `"A"`,
- clicks on B and C the response is: `"B|C"`,
- clicks on E, J, and O the response is `"E|J|O"`

My constrain is that user need to **select at least one letter in each row** which would return true in the regular expression.

e.g., **true/valid response strings would include**: `"A|F|K"`, or `"B|C|H|I|O"`

e.g., **invalid responses strings are**: `"A|G|H"`, or `"F|G|H|I|J|"`

It is a pitty that there is no actual AND in regular expressions, but the idea would be:

`[A-E] AND [F-J] AND [K-O]`

Any ideas how to solve that puzzle?

Comment: Is this always sorted ? If yes, `.*[A-E]+.*[F-J]+.*[K-O]+.*` should be enough.

Comment: This is actually working. I need to check later if the letter order is guaranteed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the rows and construct an expression of the type: `^[ABCDE]\|[FGHIJ]\|[KLMNO]$`. The `[]` regex operator denotes a set which will match if the string contains at least 1 element from within it. The `^` and `$` should ensure that the string matches in full with the characters you are expecting.

If your characters will always be ordered, you could simply replace the above regex and instead of the whole character set per row you do `[first_col_char-last-row_char]`,

Comment: @Kalaschnik: How are the rows being constructed? You could construct your verification model as part of your table.